# HTTP-Authentication: how to quickly test client software through BASIC and DIGEST?

Tags: testing, client, http-authentication, digest, basic-authentication

I'm developping a Java software that should make requests towards URLs over HTTP. Some of these URLs will need **HTTP authentication through DIGEST or BASIC**.

My client software will only contact these URLs, and if HTTP response is HTTP_OK(200), it will write output into a file.

Q1 : I would like to know what is the **quickest and easiest** way to test the HTTP authentication DIGEST and BASIC from my client side?

Q2 : Have I to install this kind of server or some "test servers" already exist on the Internet?

Q3 : If I have to install one, does it exist a quick way to install and configure it?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://httpbin.org/ or  http://requestb.in/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this question closed.

I install Tomcat server, create a simple web app and read this following information (documentation in french):

- [Tomcat : Memory Based Realm et fichier server/](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~dr/XPOSE2003/tomcat/tomcat.php?rub=20)
- [Tomcat : Sécuriser l'accès aux ressources](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~dr/XPOSE2003/tomcat/tomcat.php?rub=20)