# HTTP token authentication

Tags: http, token

After the authentication is successful, my server sends a token (`"auth=34dfea103....34df"`) to the client.

Is it possible (with a HTTP header) to mention to the client that if they want to access private data, they must return the token to prove they are identified?

Or - if it's not possible, can each request require a user name and password?

Comment: I've tried to fix the wording of your question. Please roll back if my attempt changes what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe are you talking about HTTP-Authentication? If you are using Tomcat server, it's easy to achieve this.

See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312609/http-authentication-how-to-quickly-test-client-software-through-basic-and-diges) about HTTP-Authentication ; I give a like towards french documentation for Tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

The standard mechanism for informing a client that they are not Authorized is to return a HTTP "401 Unauthorized" response... If you are using a token for auth I'm not sure if there is anyway to specify to the client how they should authenticate. You could include this in a machine parse-able (XML/JSON) body response.